# MySQL with null rows

Tags: mysql, sql, payload

i used mysql as my RDBMS and recently i have heard that you should not insert null in your DB,
i mean instead of having a lot of fields that they may or may not have value create a field and insert a data type like JSON in it.
e.g. i have table named as message
it contains fields like MessageType(it can be a map a video a photo or text,...) and it also has fields like(latitude,longitude for map),(photoid,photoPath,photoHash,... for photo),(videourl,videoHash,videoId,...) and so on. So when a message is type of text for example,it's  field has value but i pass null in other fields like latitue,videourl,...

Is it a correct approach?Can you help me with better approach?
Regards

Comment: Impossible to say, it could be but probably is not. Depends on your program, useage etc etc. What you probably have heard is someone speak about normalisation. It is too broad a subject, so if you don't have a specific normalization problem it's hard / impossible to answer, especially the way you have formed your question above. Read up a bit on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Normal_forms , and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of NULL try a different value like -1 or 0 or NA or a simple -